# Launching multiple servers with multiprocessing Process. Check whether a process has terminated

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm launching multiple servers using `multiprocessing.Process`. The server addresses are all defined in a dictionary and I want them all to be running simultaneously. I would like to find a simple way to detect when one of the server processes terminates, for some reason and relaunch them. An example of what I've got so far is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

server_dict = {"server1": "localhost, 9998", "service2": "localhost, 9999"}
running_servers = {}

def start_server(server_addr):
    server = Server(server_dict[key], RequestHandlerClass)
    p = Process(target=server.serve_forever())
    p.start()
    running_servers[key]= p


for key in server_dict:
    start_server(server_dict[key])

while True :
    for key in running_servers:
        if not running_servers[key].is_alive():
           start_server(server_dict[key])
```

This works but I there must be a better way to do this. I don't want to be constantly checking whether the process is alive or not.

Comment: You are changing the contents of `running_servers` (`start_server` does that) within a loop that iterates over its keys (`for key in running_servers`). This is probably bad, your second loop should also be `for key in server_dict`

Comment: I don't think it matters much since I'm only changes the `running_servers` content once the process is no longer alive.

Comment: As long as you don't change the keys, it will work. The suggestion is intended to prevent that you from inadvertently doing that. *Using iterkeys() while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may raise a RuntimeError or fail to iterate over all entries* [See http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iterkeys] (`for x in dict` is equivalent to `for x in dict.iterkeys()`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm not changing the keys anywhere so I don't think it will be a problem. And that is not really what I'm asking. I want to know if there is a better way to do this, like without a `running_server` dictionary or something similar to `select.epoll`. I thought about using a global `Queue` and passing that as an argument to the Server, which it can write on once it shutsdown, but there must be a more elegant way to do this

Comment: Can you hook into `SIGCHLD` (unix platform specific) and only check when you receive the signal?

Comment: Another (unix specific) method would be to open a `pipe`, such that the server has the write end and the supervisor has the read end. If the server dies, the pipe becomes readable for `select`.

Comment: @Helmut that is exactly what I was looking for! I have to familiarize myself with the `Pipe` function in `multiprocessing`. It seems to be similar to the `Queue` function except only with two endpoints. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only changes I would recommend are:

1. Insert a call to [`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) within the `while True` loop but outside the `for` loop. Select the delay value depending on how fast you want to restart a terminated server. That would stop your program from extensive and unnecessary use of CPU time. Using `sleep` is a very common coding pattern in such context.
2. Do not iterate over `running_servers`. Iterate over `tuple(running_servers.keys())` (`tuple` is needed only for Python 3 where `keys()` returns an iterator).

The other possible option is to use a pool of threads, one thread per process. Waiting for a single process to terminate and restarting it is usually not a problem. Unfortunately, there is no portable alternative to Windows' `WaitForMultipleObjects()` API call.

These solutions seem to be portable and work at least for *nix and Windows. But if you do not need portability, there are other ways to do the job. @Helmut's comment shows a *nix-specific solution. On Windows it is usually possible to use `WaitForMultipleObjects`.